# Why do explicit lifetime annotations trigger double mutable borrow errors?

Tags: rust

Given examples as

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = 0u64;

    let mut a = A {
        x: "hello".to_string(),
        y: &v,
    };

    a.hello();
    a.world();
}

struct A<'a> {
    x: String,
    y: &'a u64,
}


impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn hello(&'a mut self) {
        self.world();

        self.x = "hello123".to_string();

        let _ = *self.y;

        self.world();
    }

    fn world(&mut self) {
        self.x = "world".to_string();
    }
}
```

building it produces error as

```bash
   |
9  |     a.hello();
   |     --------- first mutable borrow occurs here
10 |     a.world();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     first borrow later used here
```

However, changing the signature of `A::hello` (i.e. eliminating the explicit `'a` annotation) to

```bash
fn hello(&mut self)
```

will fix the program.

Comment: `&'a mut self` is (almost?) always wrong.

Comment: The explicit annotation makes the lifetime of the `self` borrow and the lifetime of the data inside `A` identical, meaning that `A` will be borrowed until the end of its lifetime, and `hello()` can be called at most once. You can add an explicit lifetime to the `self` borrow, but it needs to be declared on the function, not the impl, so it's distinct from the lifetime of the data inside of `A`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's fine if `'a` is a lifetime parameter of the function. It's almost always redundant, but there are use cases.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, I meant when `'a` is a parameter of the struct.

Comment: **meaning that A will be borrowed until the end of its lifetime, and hello() can be called at most once**, this rule applies to `world()` as well right? @SvenMarnach

Comment: Without the explicit `'a` annotation on `A::hello`, the compiler restricts the lifetime of mutable borrow of `a` to line `a.hello();` only, so that the `a.world()` is allowed. Is it right? @SvenMarnach

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't the explicit lifetime, it's using the *same* lifetime for both the mutable borrow and the data inside of `A`.
When we write out the lifetimes that are elided the version without explicit annotation becomes

```rust
impl<'a> A<'a> {
    fn hello<'b>(&'b mut self) {
        //…
    }
}
```

By forcing `'a` and `'b` to be the same (in your case through reusing `'a`) you tell the compiler that the borrow of `self` should last as long as the reference inside of the `A` and since all references stored inside of `A` have to outlive it that's at least until the `A` goes out of scope.
That means once you call your `hello` the instance of `A` is borrowed for the rest of it's lifetime, since that borrow is exclusive you can't borrow it anywhere else.

That problem does not exist for the `world` function since you don't force the interior lifetime on it's borrow.